# how to check if entity is modified in form symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need know if a `articulo` is modified in my form, but when I find `pedido` before or after of `handleRequest`, always save the same object.
I need check if a `articulo` is modified, how can I get it?

This is my code:

```
    $pedido = $em->getRepository('PedidosBundle:Pedido')->find($id);

    ...

    $formulario->handleRequest($request);
    if($formulario->isValid()){
        $pedidoAuxiliar = $em->getRepository('PedidosBundle:Pedido')->find($id);//COPIA NO MODIFICADA POR EL FORMULARIO
        ...
        foreach($pedido->getArticulos() as $articulo){//ACTUAL PEDIDO PASADO POR FORMULARIO
        //$exist = false; //Para controlar si existia este articulo o si es nuevo.
            foreach($pedidoAuxiliar->getArticulos() as $articuloAuxiliar){// PEDIDO SIN PASAR POR EL FORMULARIO
                if($articuloAuxiliar->getId() == $articulo->getId()){//SI ESTE ARTICULO ESTABA AÑADIDO ANTES DE EDITAR EL PEDIDO
                    //$exist=true;
                    dump($articuloAuxiliar);
                    dump($articulo);
                    die();
                    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The second find after form validity check does not actually query the database for the old value: entity manager has already that entity reference stored so it will just return it without performing an additional query to the database (and hence this the entity returned by the second find is the exact same one as you are modifying in your function).

You could for example just store the original article ids in a temporary array (before hanbleRequest) and compare this array to the modified entity ids (whether this is enough in your case depends of course on what you actually want to do with the changed article entities)

**UPDATED**

same applied into the code

```
$pedido = $em->getRepository('PedidosBundle:Pedido')->find($id);
$articleIds = array();

// get the original article ids
foreach($pedido->getArticulos() as $articulo)
{
    articleIds[] = $articulo->getId();
}

...

$formulario->handleRequest($request);
if($formulario->isValid())
{
    ...
    foreach($pedido->getArticulos() as $articulo)
    {
        $exist = false; // whether the article existed previosly

        // check if the article exists
        if(in_array($articulo->getId(), articleIds))
        {
            $exist=true;
            //dump($articuloAuxiliar);
            dump($articulo);
            die();
            ...
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer with an example how to use a separate array to check for new articles...

Comment: @ejuhjav Why use 2 `foreach`? You can use directly in the first `if(in_array($articulo->getId(), articleIds)){ # your code... }`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Your code (and the answer) just checks whether an article exists before and after the form submission, i.e. I don't know what you mean by 'same entity' in your comment?

Comment: @gp_sflover cheers - no reason at all (save for laziness with the example as the main point was to answer to the question why the entities were the same with the two finds). updated the code example.

Comment: @ejuhjav Yes I know, I just wanted to add something useful to improve your response. In any case (I don't remember if it works only on managed entities or you need to call manually `$uow->computeChangeSets();` before... I haven't the time to check) if @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan need this check only to avoid a query to DB it's also possible to do it asking directly to Doctrine if something was changed before flush passing the entity to the `$uow` like this: `$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork(); $changeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);`